# Linq to XML: Returning attributes from Children of the same name and Parents of the same name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml

So, the noobie question of the day...

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<result>
  <rowSet name="name">
    <row name="name1" />
    <row name="name2" />
    <row name="name3" />
  </rowSet>
  <rowSet name="type">
    <row type="type1" />
    <row type="type2" />
    <row type="type3" />
  </rowSet>

etc..

</result>
```

I've been trying, and rather unsuccessfully, to get the row attributes from a single rowSet based off the rowSet:attribute name.  In other words, I'm trying to pull the attributes from the "row"s which are only contained under a rowSet:Attribute of a specific name.

I've tried using:

```
    var rowSet = from rs in xmlDoc.Descendants("result")
                 where rs.Descendants("rowset").Attributes("name").Any(a => a.Value == "name")
                 select new
                 {
                     row = from r in xmlDoc.Descendants("row")
                           select new
                           {
                               skillID = r.Attribute("name"),
                           }
                 };
```

However, this doesn't give more than a single result.  Been rather frustrating, and yet again...after trying 15 different suggestions I have been unable to remember the original code for the reader.

An answer was given:

```
var rowNames = (from i in xmlDoc.Descendants("rowSet")
                where (string)i.Attribute("name") == "name"
                select i.Descendants("row")) // Had to move this last ) to...
               .Select(r => (string)r.Attribute("name")); // Here in order to get it to work
```

I believe this worked but I'm too noobish to find out how to iterate through it, even though I can get to the data through the "Result View" of the debugger when the program is running.

---

Ok, so I'm able to get that query to run right (by moving a ")" first) and when I start stepping through the code, the rowNames has values in it.  However, I've been very unsuccessful in displaying the information in any way. I'm playing with this in a console app, fyi.

So that's the first problem.

The second is, if I start making my XML a bit more complicated, by adding multiple attributes to the row elements, like:

```
<result>
    <rowSet name="name">
        <row fName="Ted" lName = "Happy" />
        <row name="Billy" lName = "Maddison"/>
        <row name="John" lName = "Doe"/>
    </rowSet>
    <rowSet name="type">
        <row type="type1" type2 ="Hero"/>
        <row type="type2" type2 ="Villain" />
        <row type="type3" type2 ="Neutral"/>
    </rowSet>
</result>
```

How then do I retrieve all attributes in an element?

This seems so basic, which is why I'm feeling quite retarded at the moment.

Comment: Can you clarify the desired output?

Comment: Just looking to return the attributes of the different "row"s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the names alone easily enough:

```
var rowNames = from i in xmlDoc.Descendants("rowSet")
               where (string)i.Attribute("name") == "name"
               from r in i.Descendants("row")
               select (string)r.Attribute("name");
```

Just adjust the strings to get the other.  (You might throw this in a method and use parameters, for example.)

Comment: Moving the paren will cause the query to behave very differently.  Please try exactly my answer, and iterate through it like this: `foreach (string str in rowNames) Console.WriteLine(str);` -- you should see all of the attributes you want from the first rowSet.

Comment: I get an error:

Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Attribute' and no extension method 'Attribute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit guesswork, but do you mean:

```
from rs in xmlDoc.Descendants("result").Descendants("rowSet")
where (string)rs.Attribute("name") == "name"
from r in rs.Descendants("row")
select new { skillID = (string)r.Attribute("type") }
```